# Getting chat room notifications for someone else

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

I've gotten a couple notifications about messages to me in a chatroom for javascript. Although, when I click on these, they are another user who apparently also has the username Tom.

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1779526/tom

Chat Log: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17152651#17152651

Seems like a bug to me. Is there anything I can do to stop getting those notifications?

Comment: Related: [Disable three-letter pings from chat to save Oliver, Olivier and Olive from Oli's pings](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234029)

Comment: Change your user name.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I know that would probably resolve this for me personally, but it's still a bug. Notifications shouldn't be sent to users that glanced at the chat room a week ago when there is another user actively chatting there.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I got one too: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17690780#17690780

Comment: I'm getting this issue with '@all'. If it's not considered a bug, there should be an option for users to disable short match hilights.

Comment: Also: [Stack Exchange chat name mention inbox confusion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66290) (marked [meta-tag:status-bydesign]).

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. A `@name` ping matches *everybody* who's recently been in the room and whose name starts with `name` and pings them all.

If you want to ping one specific person use their full name.

If two or more people share the same name then you are going to either have to live with it or persuade one (or more) of them to change their names.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to edit the question with [tag:status-bydesign] then?

Comment: Can you explain why is it designed like that? Seems to create unnecessary noise without an apparent good reason.