# Please do not send me a notification when someone else with the same username is pinged

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications

Occasionally, I'll visit a chatroom to ask for help with an issue that wouldn't make a very good Stack Overflow post. I have a very common username, so oftentimes, I happen to have the same handle as one of the room's regulars. When the other Kevin is pinged, I receive notifications as though I had been pinged as well for a couple of weeks after visiting the room.

This is annoying. Seeing a red number pop up in the top bar to let me know of a chatroom post directed to someone else entirely adds a lot of noise, especially when I am actually expecting notifications for posts or comments I have made.

Can you please adjust the notification system in chatrooms so that when a user is pinged, they're the only one who is notified, not all users that happen to have the same username?

Comment: yeah, this happens to me every time you visit js chat! but it's never left a notification in my inbox on the main site like a direct ping to @kevinb does.

Comment: The problem is... the only way to really fix this would be to force us to use userid's in our ping, or to select someone from a list when we type an @mention (which could have similar problems). Who all do we include in said list? Just the users currently in the room wouldn't be enough.

Comment: [Rename to Tim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132562/158100)

Comment: Not going to dupe vote this as you're asking for a feature while this one describes the bug: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260671/getting-chat-room-notifications-for-someone-else it is status-bydesign also relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263978/rfc-better-chat-mentions?rq=1

Comment: @KevinB I didn't realize my visits to the JS room were causing you to get spurious pings. Would you like me to do anything to avoid that for you?

Comment: Good point about how difficult it would be to specify a userid in a @metion, as well. What I'm asking for could potentially require some drastic changes... But I had an idea for something that would make me happy that I posted as an answer below that wouldn't require changing the behavior of mentions.

Comment: @Kevin no, it doesn't bother me. continue a normal :) The regulars all use my full username, so the exceptions i generally ignore.

Comment: @KevinB Sounds good, thanks! :)

Comment: See also https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/938/what-are-the-rules-for-when-chat-messages-appear-in-a-users-inbox/939#939

Answer (score 2):

One thought I had, something that would probably be easy to implement while still making me happy, is: Would it be possible for me to click a button when I'm done visiting a chatroom that says I don't want to be pinged when I'm mentioned in the room anymore?

If I don't visit a room for a couple of weeks, I quit being pinged in it, and that's really all I want. If I can cut those two weeks short when I want to, then I quit getting so many annoying notifications.

Comment: Yes. [Leaving the chat room will prevent pings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275726/how-do-i-remove-myself-from-a-chat/275732#275732). (That said, I have no idea why your feature request has been as controversial as it is. This brokenness has been around in chat forever, and is really past time of needing to be fixed.)

Comment: @CodyGray I had no idea that was an option! Thank you for letting me know!

Comment: @davidism Yes, but only for two days. That's much, much better than what I've been experiencing, and it gives people a chance to get a hold of me if they need to.

Comment: We have ~5 Kevins in the Python room. They regularly wish for a "stop notifications immediately" feature.

Comment: @davidism well, we know there's only one *True Kevin* in Room 6 - the others might just have to consider renaming themselves :)